# Understanding the algorithm of Median of Two Sorted Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

There are two sorted arrays A and B of size m and n respectively. Find the median of the two sorted arrays. The overall run time complexity should be O(log (m+n)).

I don't understand the formulas for calculating aMid, and bMid. What's the logic behind these formulas?

**int aMid = aLen * k / (aLen + bLen); // a's middle count**

**int bMid = k - aMid - 1; // b's middle count**

Here is the link to program. 
http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/leetcode-median-of-two-sorted-arrays-java/][1]

```
public static double findMedianSortedArrays(int A[], int B[]) {
    int m = A.length;
    int n = B.length;

    if ((m + n) % 2 != 0) // odd
        return (double) findKth(A, B, (m + n) / 2, 0, m - 1, 0, n - 1);
    else { // even
        return (findKth(A, B, (m + n) / 2, 0, m - 1, 0, n - 1) 
            + findKth(A, B, (m + n) / 2 - 1, 0, m - 1, 0, n - 1)) * 0.5;
    }
}

public static int findKth(int A[], int B[], int k, 
    int aStart, int aEnd, int bStart, int bEnd) {

    int aLen = aEnd - aStart + 1;
    int bLen = bEnd - bStart + 1;

    // Handle special cases
    if (aLen == 0)
        return B[bStart + k];
    if (bLen == 0)
        return A[aStart + k];
    if (k == 0)
        return A[aStart] < B[bStart] ? A[aStart] : B[bStart];

    int aMid = aLen * k / (aLen + bLen); // a's middle count    
                                      // I AM STUCK HERE

    int bMid = k - aMid - 1; // b's middle count

    // make aMid and bMid to be array index
    aMid = aMid + aStart;
    bMid = bMid + bStart;

    if (A[aMid] > B[bMid]) {
        k = k - (bMid - bStart + 1);
        aEnd = aMid;
        bStart = bMid + 1;
    } else {
        k = k - (aMid - aStart + 1);
        bEnd = bMid;
        aStart = aMid + 1;
    }

    return findKth(A, B, k, aStart, aEnd, bStart, bEnd);
}
```

I got some idea, from the comments with the code, how these formulas are calculated but still don't understand to explain to someone "why these formulas" Or what's the logic behind these formulas?

For int aMid = aLen * k / (aLen + bLen); // a's middle count 
As aMid = aLen / 2 --(i)

and k = （aLen + bLen)/2, -->2 = (aLen + bLen)/k

putting value of 2 in equ (i)

so aMid = aLen/(aLen + bLen)/k== aLen *k/ (aLen+bLen)

and for int bMid = k - aMid - 1; // b's middle count

aMid + bMid + 1 = k must be satisfied to be able to make the conclusions it does when A[aMid] > B[bMid]

As for why aMid + bMid + 1 = k is significant: If A[aMid] is greater than B[bMid], you know that any elements in after A[aMid] in A can't be the kth element since there are too many elements in B lower than it (and would exceed k elements). You also know that B[bMid] and any element before B[bMid] in B can't be the kth element since there are too few elements in A lower than it (there wouldn't be enough elements before B[bMid] to be the kth element).

Comment: The best way to work it out is to try to work it out for yourself.  How would you do it?  What would be the best guess for to start at the middle is you assume the two arrays have the same distribution of numbers?

Comment: Your second line is incorrect. `k` can be different when this method is called recursively.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i tried to do it myself but i was totally lost how to do it. There are other algorithms for calculating median and i fully understand them but they find median for two equal arrays. I like this one because it's more general algorithm.  Which 2nd line is incorrect? Yes, you are right k can be different when this method is called recursively.

Comment: The second line of your explanation.  You assume `k` is always calculated the same way.

Comment: @peterLawrey yes you are right, my assumption was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already mentioned: `aMid + bMid + 1 = k` must be satisfied to be able to make the conclusions that:
 
when `A[aMid] > B[bMid]` we can throw away everything before `bMid` and everything after (including) `aMid`, 
because we know that there are `bMid` + `aMid` + `1` (from including `aMid`) `= k` elements smaller than `A[aMid]`. Therefor our median lies in the remaining arrays.

With this in mind it does not really matter how we set up our two mid values `aMid` and `bMid` in the first place. The only thing to take care of is not letting one of them cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
int aMid = 0;
int bMid = k - aMid - 1;
if(bMid >= bLen) {
    bMid = bLen - 1;
    aMid = k - bMid - 1;
}
```

Would do the trick as well. But it would take more than `O(log(n+m))` time because in the worst case we only always skip one element (`A[0]`).
What we want is to always throw away a percentage of `aLen + bLen`.
In our case this is:

> A > B: k = k - (bMid +1) = k - (k - aMid) = aMid = k * (aLen / (aLen + bLen))
>   B > A: k = k - (aMid + 1) = k - (k * aLen / (aLen + bLen)) -1 = k * (bLen / (aLen + bLen)) - 1

Ignoring the -1 and assuming that the probability for `A > B` is the same as `B > A` we get:
 `E(k) = 0.5 * k * (aLen/(aLen + bLen)) + 0.5 * k * (bLen/(aLen + bLen))`
 `= 0.5 * k (aLen + bLen)/(aLen + bLen) = 0.5 * k`
Meaning that we get approximately `O(log(n + m))` recursive calls until `k` is 0 and then the functions stops.

Comment: I am abit confused about the line  k = k - (bMid - bStart + 1);  As (A[aMid] > B[bMid]) so all the values before bMid + bMid itself can't be K so subtract it from K but why 1 is added? I am totally confused about 1.

Comment: We have the values `B[bStart], B[bStart+1], B[bStart+2], ..., B[bMid]` which are all smaller than `A[aMid]`. And those are `bMid - bStart + 1` elements. Example: `B[3], B[4], B[5], B[6]` are `6 - 3 + 1 = 4` Elements. Whitout `+1` we get `3`.